# Use Github Project as API in Visual Studio with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, github, github-api

I am totally new to Github and I wanted to use a TeamSpeak 3 API in Visual Studio with C#. The API: https://github.com/nikeee/TeamSpeak3QueryAPI

I am not able to get it into my Visual Studio to use it as Libary.

I would be able to integrate a dll or something else, but there is any dll for the API.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Since there is no nuget package yet and I didn't see a binary download, I guess you'll have to clone and build it yourself. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
Works fine!